# PhotoSwipe Base64 Placeholder Into Canvas & Blurred

Tags: javascript, html, css, base64, photoswipe

How can this effect https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/PyBpgY , blurring tiny on page base64 images in PhotoSwipe's lightbox array be achieved ?

HTML

```
<section class="wrapper">
<div class="aspect-ratio-fill">
    <div class="progressiveMedia">
      <canvas class="progressiveMedia__canvas" width="75" height="38.671875"></canvas>
    <img class="progressiveMedia__image" data-src="http://staging.weate.ch.stage18.535e.blackmesh.com/poc/blurup/images/617902.jpg"/>
    <img class="progressiveMedia__thumbnail" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAAA8AAD/4QMdaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wLwA8P3hwYWNrZXQgYmVnaW49Iu+7vyIgaWQ9Ilc1TTBNcENlaGlIenJlU3pOVGN6a2M5ZCI/PiA8eDp4bXBtZXRhIHhtbG5zOng9ImFkb2JlOm5zOm1ldGEvIiB4OnhtcHRrPSJBZG9iZSBYTVAgQ29yZSA1LjUtYzAyMSA3OS4xNTU3NzIsIDIwMTQvMDEvMTMtMTk6NDQ6MDAgICAgICAgICI+IDxyZGY6UkRGIHhtbG5zOnJkZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS8wMi8yMi1yZGYtc3ludGF4LW5zIyI+IDxyZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24gcmRmOmFib3V0PSIiIHhtbG5zOnhtcE1NPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvbW0vIiB4bWxuczpzdFJlZj0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL3NUeXBlL1Jlc291cmNlUmVmIyIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bXBNTTpEb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOjU5REY4M0QzNkM2QzExRTc4OTNDRUJENjNFRTYyQjRGIiB4bXBNTTpJbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOjU5REY4M0QyNkM2QzExRTc4OTNDRUJENjNFRTYyQjRGIiB4bXA6Q3JlYXRvclRvb2w9IkFkb2JlIFBob3Rvc2hvcCBDQyAyMDE0IFdpbmRvd3MiPiA8eG1wTU06RGVyaXZlZEZyb20gc3RSZWY6aW5zdGFuY2VJRD0iQkIzOTJFQkM3Rjg0MDE1Mzk2NEY3QURGQkUyQTlCNTUiIHN0UmVmOmRvY3VtZW50SUQ9IkJCMzkyRUJDN0Y4NDAxNTM5NjRGN0FERkJFMkE5QjU1Ii8+IDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPiA8L3JkZjpSREY+IDwveDp4bXBtZXRhPiA8P3hwYWNrZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+/+4ADkFkb2JlAGTAAAAAAf/bAIQABgQEBAUEBgUFBgkGBQYJCwgGBggLDAoKCwoKDBAMDAwMDAwQDA4PEA8ODBMTFBQTExwbGxscHx8fHx8fHx8fHwEHBwcNDA0YEBAYGhURFRofHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHx8f/8AAEQgAFQAoAwERAAIRAQMRAf/EAIcAAAICAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQFAAYCAwcBAAMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFABAAAgECBQIEAwkAAAAAAAAAAQIDEQQAEhMFBiExUWFCByIUFUFxocEyI1MkFhEAAQMCBAQFBQAAAAAAAAAAAQACAxESIaEiEzFRcQQyQlIUFfBhgZGx/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwA+L3n4BKNS522+tFqVCzRUao70MecGmMIj7lp8Oa7PuO3e3F9D0UufdjgclsJEspQHqI2dGoaeICgjF2mf0qD/AG9K7gXPOae5bCSBdg2vXiY57m4kglVQoNNOPOBmJHq7DGyMy0xC5sr4q4EJbd8/4s4IkM8Mn8UluQwPmQTg7rwcQk2WHEFVbdeZyPdxja4tW3XrMZFIL1+xR3Wnjg7zkNhqcXfJOfx2K3cvJp0tZgI+kkcTEitAI0XMv34faPElIJB4QMk227lHIDsgXfL+42/aLmgG8qJ3uSF/UYYiVBr2YuQMVbUCpFBzWeRouoMTyVZh/wBHvm4SMly6xzVWW/aXLGwjqFeRVLHqvpUAYpEySQ6SkmkhibqHRYScTvogUN1ZOwqVVmatPEkrWnlivxz+bVH5WL0v/SXy7Xc7fMhgljnlZKFrYUC1NMheQ/jTGSaHbIxDui3wdxugktc0ff8AqsQ+mi5t/mBKwqfl9bIE1fLJU1phnUqKr2q3BRTY6khvRHrEiiktpLH6ASRmbzJAxeDZ83HJZ5t3y5cUHuhteuYCmT4BAXzE+XSoXAntrpyTQX2C7Oi07ef6jaAi7jU6/vUp684r+WJC1F1/4yQW6aupF9TJ0snwCQGlPRUqfDwwW21F1KfXJHVQ21uzzX//2Q==" />
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  color: #000;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.aspect-ratio-fill {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.progressiveMedia {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.progressiveMedia.isImageLoaded > .progressiveMedia__image {
  opacity: 1;
}

.progressiveMedia__thumbnail {
  display: none;
}

.progressiveMedia__image,
.progressiveMedia__canvas {
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.progressiveMedia__image {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 400ms 0ms;
  z-index: 1;
}
.progressiveMedia.isImageLoaded .progressiveMedia__canvas{
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s linear .5s,opacity .1s .4s;
    transition: visibility 0s linear .5s,opacity .1s .4s;
}
```

JS

```
function init() {

    const blurdelay = 1000;//The delay to see the fade in.
    var blurRadius = 7; 

    var component = document.querySelector('.progressiveMedia');
    var image     = document.querySelector('.progressiveMedia__image');
    var canvas    = document.querySelector('.progressiveMedia__canvas');
    var thumbnail = document.querySelector('.progressiveMedia__thumbnail');

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //The aspect-ratio-fill padding is set here.
    var aspectRatioFill = document.querySelector('.aspect-ratio-fill');
    var percentage = (thumbnail.naturalHeight / thumbnail.naturalWidth) * 100;
    aspectRatioFill.style.paddingBottom = `${percentage}%`;

    //Draw the thumbnail onto the canvas, then blur it
    drawThumbnail(blurRadius);

    //Load the image in. Once it's loaded, add a class to the component wrapper that fades in the image and fades out the canvas element.
    image.src = image.dataset.src;
    image.addEventListener('load', function onImageLoaded() {
        image.removeEventListener('load', onImageLoaded);

        // This delay is only set so the we can see the blur effect more clearly on page load  
        setTimeout(function () {
            component.classList.add('isImageLoaded');
        }, blurdelay);      
    });

    //Draws the thumbnail into the canvas and blurs it
    function drawThumbnail(blur) {
            context
            .drawImage(thumbnail, 0, 0, thumbnail.naturalWidth,
                                thumbnail.naturalHeight, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        StackBlur.canvasRGBA(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, blur);
    }

}

// Set a timeout so we make sure StackBlur is defined
setTimeout(init, 0);






/**
 * StackBlur.js
 * from https://github.com/flozz/StackBlur/
 */
(function(f){if(typeof exports==="object"&&typeof module!=="undefined"){module.exports=f()}else if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd){define([],f)}else{var g;if(typeof window!=="undefined"){g=window}else if(typeof global!=="undefined"){g=global}else if(typeof self!=="undefined"){g=self}else{g=this}g.StackBlur = f()}})(function(){var define,module,exports;return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
/*
    StackBlur - a fast almost Gaussian Blur For Canvas

    Version:     0.5
    Author:        Mario Klingemann
    Contact:     mario@quasimondo.com
    Website:    http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas
    Twitter:    @quasimondo

    In case you find this class useful - especially in commercial projects -
    I am not totally unhappy for a small donation to my PayPal account
    mario@quasimondo.de

    Or support me on flattr:
    https://flattr.com/thing/72791/StackBlur-a-fast-almost-Gaussian-Blur-Effect-for-CanvasJavascript

    Copyright (c) 2010 Mario Klingemann

    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
    obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
    files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
    restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
    copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
    copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
    Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
    conditions:

    The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
    included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
    EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
    OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
    NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
    HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
    WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
    FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
    OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
    */


var mul_table = [
    512,512,456,512,328,456,335,512,405,328,271,456,388,335,292,512,
    454,405,364,328,298,271,496,456,420,388,360,335,312,292,273,512,
    482,454,428,405,383,364,345,328,312,298,284,271,259,496,475,456,
    437,420,404,388,374,360,347,335,323,312,302,292,282,273,265,512,
    497,482,468,454,441,428,417,405,394,383,373,364,354,345,337,328,
    320,312,305,298,291,284,278,271,265,259,507,496,485,475,465,456,
    446,437,428,420,412,404,396,388,381,374,367,360,354,347,341,335,
    329,323,318,312,307,302,297,292,287,282,278,273,269,265,261,512,
    505,497,489,482,475,468,461,454,447,441,435,428,422,417,411,405,
    399,394,389,383,378,373,368,364,359,354,350,345,341,337,332,328,
    324,320,316,312,309,305,301,298,294,291,287,284,281,278,274,271,
    268,265,262,259,257,507,501,496,491,485,480,475,470,465,460,456,
    451,446,442,437,433,428,424,420,416,412,408,404,400,396,392,388,
    385,381,377,374,370,367,363,360,357,354,350,347,344,341,338,335,
    332,329,326,323,320,318,315,312,310,307,304,302,299,297,294,292,
    289,287,285,282,280,278,275,273,271,269,267,265,263,261,259];


var shg_table = [
    9, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17,
    17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19,
    19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20,
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21,
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22,
    22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22,
    22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23,
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24 ];


function processImage(img, canvas, radius, blurAlphaChannel)
{
    if (typeof(img) == 'string') {
        var img = document.getElementById(img);
    }
    else if (!img instanceof HTMLImageElement) {
        return;
    }
    var w = img.naturalWidth;
    var h = img.naturalHeight;

    if (typeof(canvas) == 'string') {
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas);
    }
    else if (!canvas instanceof HTMLCanvasElement) {
        return;
    }

    canvas.style.width  = w + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = h + 'px';
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    if (isNaN(radius) || radius < 1) return;

    if (blurAlphaChannel)
        processCanvasRGBA(canvas, 0, 0, w, h, radius);
    else
        processCanvasRGB(canvas, 0, 0, w, h, radius);
}

function getImageDataFromCanvas(canvas, top_x, top_y, width, height)
{
    if (typeof(canvas) == 'string')
        var canvas  = document.getElementById(canvas);
    else if (!canvas instanceof HTMLCanvasElement)
        return;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageData;

    try {
        try {
            imageData = context.getImageData(top_x, top_y, width, height);
        } catch(e) {

            // NOTE: this part is supposedly only needed if you want to work with local files
            // so it might be okay to remove the whole try/catch block and just use
            // imageData = context.getImageData(top_x, top_y, width, height);
            try {
                netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
                imageData = context.getImageData(top_x, top_y, width, height);
            } catch(e) {
                alert("Cannot access local image");
                throw new Error("unable to access local image data: " + e);
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch(e) {
        alert("Cannot access image");
        throw new Error("unable to access image data: " + e);
    }

    return imageData;
}

function processCanvasRGBA(canvas, top_x, top_y, width, height, radius)
{
    if (isNaN(radius) || radius < 1) return;
    radius |= 0;

    var imageData = getImageDataFromCanvas(canvas, top_x, top_y, width, height);

    imageData = processImageDataRGBA(imageData, top_x, top_y, width, height, radius);

    canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(imageData, top_x, top_y);
}

function processImageDataRGBA(imageData, top_x, top_y, width, height, radius)
{
    var pixels = imageData.data;

    var x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw, r_sum, g_sum, b_sum, a_sum,
        r_out_sum, g_out_sum, b_out_sum, a_out_sum,
        r_in_sum, g_in_sum, b_in_sum, a_in_sum,
        pr, pg, pb, pa, rbs;

    var div = radius + radius + 1;
    var w4 = width << 2;
    var widthMinus1  = width - 1;
    var heightMinus1 = height - 1;
    var radiusPlus1  = radius + 1;
    var sumFactor = radiusPlus1 * (radiusPlus1 + 1) / 2;

    var stackStart = new BlurStack();
    var stack = stackStart;
    for (i = 1; i < div; i++)
    {
        stack = stack.next = new BlurStack();
        if (i == radiusPlus1) var stackEnd = stack;
    }
    stack.next = stackStart;
    var stackIn = null;
    var stackOut = null;

    yw = yi = 0;

    var mul_sum = mul_table[radius];
    var shg_sum = shg_table[radius];

    for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        r_in_sum = g_in_sum = b_in_sum = a_in_sum = r_sum = g_sum = b_sum = a_sum = 0;

        r_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pr = pixels[yi]);
        g_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pg = pixels[yi+1]);
        b_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pb = pixels[yi+2]);
        a_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pa = pixels[yi+3]);

        r_sum += sumFactor * pr;
        g_sum += sumFactor * pg;
        b_sum += sumFactor * pb;
        a_sum += sumFactor * pa;

        stack = stackStart;

        for (i = 0; i < radiusPlus1; i++)
        {
            stack.r = pr;
            stack.g = pg;
            stack.b = pb;
            stack.a = pa;
            stack = stack.next;
        }

        for (i = 1; i < radiusPlus1; i++)
        {
            p = yi + ((widthMinus1 < i ? widthMinus1 : i) << 2);
            r_sum += (stack.r = (pr = pixels[p])) * (rbs = radiusPlus1 - i);
            g_sum += (stack.g = (pg = pixels[p+1])) * rbs;
            b_sum += (stack.b = (pb = pixels[p+2])) * rbs;
            a_sum += (stack.a = (pa = pixels[p+3])) * rbs;

            r_in_sum += pr;
            g_in_sum += pg;
            b_in_sum += pb;
            a_in_sum += pa;

            stack = stack.next;
        }


        stackIn = stackStart;
        stackOut = stackEnd;
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            pixels[yi+3] = pa = (a_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
            if (pa != 0)
            {
                pa = 255 / pa;
                pixels[yi]   = ((r_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
                pixels[yi+1] = ((g_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
                pixels[yi+2] = ((b_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
            } else {
                pixels[yi] = pixels[yi+1] = pixels[yi+2] = 0;
            }

            r_sum -= r_out_sum;
            g_sum -= g_out_sum;
            b_sum -= b_out_sum;
            a_sum -= a_out_sum;

            r_out_sum -= stackIn.r;
            g_out_sum -= stackIn.g;
            b_out_sum -= stackIn.b;
            a_out_sum -= stackIn.a;

            p =  (yw + ((p = x + radius + 1) < widthMinus1 ? p : widthMinus1)) << 2;

            r_in_sum += (stackIn.r = pixels[p]);
            g_in_sum += (stackIn.g = pixels[p+1]);
            b_in_sum += (stackIn.b = pixels[p+2]);
            a_in_sum += (stackIn.a = pixels[p+3]);

            r_sum += r_in_sum;
            g_sum += g_in_sum;
            b_sum += b_in_sum;
            a_sum += a_in_sum;

            stackIn = stackIn.next;

            r_out_sum += (pr = stackOut.r);
            g_out_sum += (pg = stackOut.g);
            b_out_sum += (pb = stackOut.b);
            a_out_sum += (pa = stackOut.a);

            r_in_sum -= pr;
            g_in_sum -= pg;
            b_in_sum -= pb;
            a_in_sum -= pa;

            stackOut = stackOut.next;

            yi += 4;
        }
        yw += width;
    }


    for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        g_in_sum = b_in_sum = a_in_sum = r_in_sum = g_sum = b_sum = a_sum = r_sum = 0;

        yi = x << 2;
        r_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pr = pixels[yi]);
        g_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pg = pixels[yi+1]);
        b_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pb = pixels[yi+2]);
        a_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pa = pixels[yi+3]);

        r_sum += sumFactor * pr;
        g_sum += sumFactor * pg;
        b_sum += sumFactor * pb;
        a_sum += sumFactor * pa;

        stack = stackStart;

        for (i = 0; i < radiusPlus1; i++)
        {
            stack.r = pr;
            stack.g = pg;
            stack.b = pb;
            stack.a = pa;
            stack = stack.next;
        }

        yp = width;

        for (i = 1; i <= radius; i++)
        {
            yi = (yp + x) << 2;

            r_sum += (stack.r = (pr = pixels[yi])) * (rbs = radiusPlus1 - i);
            g_sum += (stack.g = (pg = pixels[yi+1])) * rbs;
            b_sum += (stack.b = (pb = pixels[yi+2])) * rbs;
            a_sum += (stack.a = (pa = pixels[yi+3])) * rbs;

            r_in_sum += pr;
            g_in_sum += pg;
            b_in_sum += pb;
            a_in_sum += pa;

            stack = stack.next;

            if(i < heightMinus1)
            {
                yp += width;
            }
        }

        yi = x;
        stackIn = stackStart;
        stackOut = stackEnd;
        for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            p = yi << 2;
            pixels[p+3] = pa = (a_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
            if (pa > 0)
            {
                pa = 255 / pa;
                pixels[p]   = ((r_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
                pixels[p+1] = ((g_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
                pixels[p+2] = ((b_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
            } else {
                pixels[p] = pixels[p+1] = pixels[p+2] = 0;
            }

            r_sum -= r_out_sum;
            g_sum -= g_out_sum;
            b_sum -= b_out_sum;
            a_sum -= a_out_sum;

            r_out_sum -= stackIn.r;
            g_out_sum -= stackIn.g;
            b_out_sum -= stackIn.b;
            a_out_sum -= stackIn.a;

            p = (x + (((p = y + radiusPlus1) < heightMinus1 ? p : heightMinus1) * width)) << 2;

            r_sum += (r_in_sum += (stackIn.r = pixels[p]));
            g_sum += (g_in_sum += (stackIn.g = pixels[p+1]));
            b_sum += (b_in_sum += (stackIn.b = pixels[p+2]));
            a_sum += (a_in_sum += (stackIn.a = pixels[p+3]));

            stackIn = stackIn.next;

            r_out_sum += (pr = stackOut.r);
            g_out_sum += (pg = stackOut.g);
            b_out_sum += (pb = stackOut.b);
            a_out_sum += (pa = stackOut.a);

            r_in_sum -= pr;
            g_in_sum -= pg;
            b_in_sum -= pb;
            a_in_sum -= pa;

            stackOut = stackOut.next;

            yi += width;
        }
    }
    return imageData;
}

function processCanvasRGB(canvas, top_x, top_y, width, height, radius)
{
    if (isNaN(radius) || radius < 1) return;
    radius |= 0;

    var imageData = getImageDataFromCanvas(canvas, top_x, top_y, width, height);
    imageData = processImageDataRGB(imageData, top_x, top_y, width, height, radius);

    canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(imageData, top_x, top_y);
}

function processImageDataRGB(imageData, top_x, top_y, width, height, radius)
{
    var pixels = imageData.data;

    var x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw, r_sum, g_sum, b_sum,
        r_out_sum, g_out_sum, b_out_sum,
        r_in_sum, g_in_sum, b_in_sum,
        pr, pg, pb, rbs;

    var div = radius + radius + 1;
    var w4 = width << 2;
    var widthMinus1  = width - 1;
    var heightMinus1 = height - 1;
    var radiusPlus1  = radius + 1;
    var sumFactor = radiusPlus1 * (radiusPlus1 + 1) / 2;

    var stackStart = new BlurStack();
    var stack = stackStart;
    for (i = 1; i < div; i++)
    {
        stack = stack.next = new BlurStack();
        if (i == radiusPlus1) var stackEnd = stack;
    }
    stack.next = stackStart;
    var stackIn = null;
    var stackOut = null;

    yw = yi = 0;

    var mul_sum = mul_table[radius];
    var shg_sum = shg_table[radius];

    for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        r_in_sum = g_in_sum = b_in_sum = r_sum = g_sum = b_sum = 0;

        r_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pr = pixels[yi]);
        g_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pg = pixels[yi+1]);
        b_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pb = pixels[yi+2]);

        r_sum += sumFactor * pr;
        g_sum += sumFactor * pg;
        b_sum += sumFactor * pb;

        stack = stackStart;

        for (i = 0; i < radiusPlus1; i++)
        {
            stack.r = pr;
            stack.g = pg;
            stack.b = pb;
            stack = stack.next;
        }

        for (i = 1; i < radiusPlus1; i++)
        {
            p = yi + ((widthMinus1 < i ? widthMinus1 : i) << 2);
            r_sum += (stack.r = (pr = pixels[p])) * (rbs = radiusPlus1 - i);
            g_sum += (stack.g = (pg = pixels[p+1])) * rbs;
            b_sum += (stack.b = (pb = pixels[p+2])) * rbs;

            r_in_sum += pr;
            g_in_sum += pg;
            b_in_sum += pb;

            stack = stack.next;
        }


        stackIn = stackStart;
        stackOut = stackEnd;
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            pixels[yi]   = (r_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
            pixels[yi+1] = (g_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
            pixels[yi+2] = (b_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;

            r_sum -= r_out_sum;
            g_sum -= g_out_sum;
            b_sum -= b_out_sum;

            r_out_sum -= stackIn.r;
            g_out_sum -= stackIn.g;
            b_out_sum -= stackIn.b;

            p =  (yw + ((p = x + radius + 1) < widthMinus1 ? p : widthMinus1)) << 2;

            r_in_sum += (stackIn.r = pixels[p]);
            g_in_sum += (stackIn.g = pixels[p+1]);
            b_in_sum += (stackIn.b = pixels[p+2]);

            r_sum += r_in_sum;
            g_sum += g_in_sum;
            b_sum += b_in_sum;

            stackIn = stackIn.next;

            r_out_sum += (pr = stackOut.r);
            g_out_sum += (pg = stackOut.g);
            b_out_sum += (pb = stackOut.b);

            r_in_sum -= pr;
            g_in_sum -= pg;
            b_in_sum -= pb;

            stackOut = stackOut.next;

            yi += 4;
        }
        yw += width;
    }


    for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        g_in_sum = b_in_sum = r_in_sum = g_sum = b_sum = r_sum = 0;

        yi = x << 2;
        r_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pr = pixels[yi]);
        g_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pg = pixels[yi+1]);
        b_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pb = pixels[yi+2]);

        r_sum += sumFactor * pr;
        g_sum += sumFactor * pg;
        b_sum += sumFactor * pb;

        stack = stackStart;

        for (i = 0; i < radiusPlus1; i++)
        {
            stack.r = pr;
            stack.g = pg;
            stack.b = pb;
            stack = stack.next;
        }

        yp = width;

        for (i = 1; i <= radius; i++)
        {
            yi = (yp + x) << 2;

            r_sum += (stack.r = (pr = pixels[yi])) * (rbs = radiusPlus1 - i);
            g_sum += (stack.g = (pg = pixels[yi+1])) * rbs;
            b_sum += (stack.b = (pb = pixels[yi+2])) * rbs;

            r_in_sum += pr;
            g_in_sum += pg;
            b_in_sum += pb;

            stack = stack.next;

            if(i < heightMinus1)
            {
                yp += width;
            }
        }

        yi = x;
        stackIn = stackStart;
        stackOut = stackEnd;
        for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            p = yi << 2;
            pixels[p]   = (r_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
            pixels[p+1] = (g_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
            pixels[p+2] = (b_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;

            r_sum -= r_out_sum;
            g_sum -= g_out_sum;
            b_sum -= b_out_sum;

            r_out_sum -= stackIn.r;
            g_out_sum -= stackIn.g;
            b_out_sum -= stackIn.b;

            p = (x + (((p = y + radiusPlus1) < heightMinus1 ? p : heightMinus1) * width)) << 2;

            r_sum += (r_in_sum += (stackIn.r = pixels[p]));
            g_sum += (g_in_sum += (stackIn.g = pixels[p+1]));
            b_sum += (b_in_sum += (stackIn.b = pixels[p+2]));

            stackIn = stackIn.next;

            r_out_sum += (pr = stackOut.r);
            g_out_sum += (pg = stackOut.g);
            b_out_sum += (pb = stackOut.b);

            r_in_sum -= pr;
            g_in_sum -= pg;
            b_in_sum -= pb;

            stackOut = stackOut.next;

            yi += width;
        }
    }

    return imageData;
}

function BlurStack()
{
    this.r = 0;
    this.g = 0;
    this.b = 0;
    this.a = 0;
    this.next = null;
}

module.exports = {
    image: processImage,
    canvasRGBA: processCanvasRGBA,
    canvasRGB: processCanvasRGB,
    imageDataRGBA: processImageDataRGBA,
    imageDataRGB: processImageDataRGB
};

},{}]},{},[1])(1)
});
```

Whilst it is possible to add the Base64 image as a placeholder in the PhotoSwipe array, it is difficult to see how to put that image into a canvas and then blur that canvas.

Does anyone know which event's to hook etc to get this to work ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add blur effect using CSS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur